# Navigation menuitems different when loading to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu-items

When I am on my local the menu items work perfectly there is 3 visible menuitems and when I hover over the first the drop down menu items appear. they are in a horizontal view and it looks great. when I load it up to my server the menu items become a list and the menu displays everything even the subcategory and it displays it vertically.   I have tried  using `RenderingMode="table"`  that displays the 3 pages and not the sub category. I then added `staticdisplaylevels="3"` the categories and the subcategories are all listed in a horizontal line. the frame work on my local is `4.0` and the server is `4.0`.  I have been trying this for several days and I just thought that I would post it up here for someone else to have a second look.

**This is my master page navigation**

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" Visible="false" onmenuitemclick="NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick" >
                    <LevelSubMenuStyles>
                        <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level1" />
                        <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level2" />
                        <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="level3" />
                    </LevelSubMenuStyles>
                    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="hoverstyle"/>
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx" Text="Page1">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub1" Value="Sub1" NavigateUrl="~/page1.aspx" >


                                <asp:MenuItem  Text="Sub1.1" Value=" Sub1.1" />
                                <asp:MenuItem  Text="Sub1.2"  Value="sub1.2"/>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="sub1.3" Value= "sub1.3"/>    
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/page2.aspx " Text="Sub2" Value="Sub2">
                                <asp:MenuItem  Text="Sub2.1" Value="sub2.1" />
                                <asp:MenuItem  Text="Sub2.2"  Value="sub2.2"/>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Sub2.3" Value= "Sub2.3" />
                        </asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/page3.aspx" Text="Page3"/>
        </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most probably your style sheet is not uploaded to your server, or you are referencing it wrong on the server? Sounds like your menu is degrading to its natural lists form?

Comment: Your markup is (as posted) is faulty - unclosed quottation as well as no closed tag for one MenuItem. Can u fix those and see if error still occurs?

Comment: Louis van Tonder all of the other style on the css file are being reference and they are working.

Comment: Yuriy Galanter this was a typo on my part when writing to here this is not the issue.

Comment: Can u post screenshots of correct and incorrect versions?

Comment: Ok so i loaded it on a local server and the navigation worked fine.  But i need it on the other server to make it a site that you can access on the www.  Soo... there is a server setting different some where.  anyone have a clue where i should look. the framework is the same?